# Mapreduce job not working for fetching data

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I have a map reduce job that I'd like to use to fetch some data from the [scholarly](https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/) package. Here's the code I've edited from the documentation:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scholarly import scholarly

def GetFirstAuthor(author_name):
    search_query = scholarly.search_author(author_name)
    first_author_result = next(search_query)
    return first_author_result

def RetrieveAuthorDetails(first_author_result):
    author = scholarly.fill(first_author_result)
    return author

def RetrievePublicationDetails(author):
    author_pub = []
    for pub in author['publications']:
        title = ''
        pub_year = 0
        author = ''
        journal = ''
        citation = ''
        
        if 'title' in pub['bib']:
            title = pub['bib']['title']
        if 'pub_year' in pub['bib']:
            pub_year = pub['bib']['pub_year']
        if 'author' in pub['bib']:
            author = pub['bib']['author']
        if 'journal' in pub['bib']:
            journal = pub['bib']['journal']
        if 'citation' in pub['bib']:
            citation = pub['bib']['citation']
            
        author_pub.append([title,pub_year,author,journal,citation])
    return author_pub

def mapper(user_name):
    try:
        first_author_result = GetFirstAuthor(user_name)
    except StopIteration:
        author_pub_details.append([user_name, 'Record not found for the author'])
        
    author = RetrieveAuthorDetails(first_author_result)
    return author, user_name

def reducer(author, user_name):
    author_pub = RetrievePublicationDetails(author)
    author_pub_details.append([user_name, author_pub])

author_pub_details = []
user_names = ['Marc Mertens','Katharina Breininger','Marie Caroline Guzian','James M. Shwayder','M. Narasimha','Brian W. Miller','Peter C. Y. Chen','Maxim N. Peshkov']
with Pool() as pool:
    author, user_name = pool.map(mapper, user_names)
    reducer(author, user_name)
```

This code works well without `mapreduce` but it seems to be stuck with it. I'm trying to run it for a small sample of 10 users and even that doesn't finish. What am I doing wrong here? It'd also be ideal to show a progress bar as the `mapreduce` job progresses.

Comment: You can temporarily comment out the `reducer` call at the end to see if the problem specifically lies in the reduce step.

Comment: I did that and it seems like the code isn't even processing the `mapper`. I put a print statement right before the `try-except` block and the code isn't even printing that.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I'm using macOS Ventura 13.4.1

Comment: On macOS, the processes are started with the "spawn" method. This means that a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard is needed. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods

Comment: I did add the line, but I get this error in the console of Jupyter Notebook:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prateeksinghal/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/prateeksinghal/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/prateeksinghal/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File ```

Comment: ```
"/Users/prateeksinghal/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 358, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'mapper' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>```

Comment: Jupyter makes things more complicated. Try to put a line `mp.set_start_method('fork')` before the `with Pool()...`. This should work on macOS but wouldn't on Windows.